# Преобразование строки в переменную

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток, возник следующий вопрос, допустим у нас есть javascript код, типа:

```
// какоето пространство имен...
var myNameSpace = {
    someFunc: function() {
        // какой-то код...
    }
};
```

И javascript код типа

```
//  на вход получаем строковые значения
var nameSpaceName = 'myNameSpace';    // имя пространства
var nameSpaceFuncName = 'someFunc';   // и имя функции

//  как вызвать nameSpaceName.nameSpaceFuncName()?
//  на ум приходит только что-то очень страшное типа
eval(nameSpaceName + '.' + nameSpaceFuncName + '()');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно вот так, но только если "пространство имен" определено в контексте window (т.е "глобально")

```
window[nameSpaceName][nameSpaceFuncName]()
```

Comment: Да, это оно, спасиб - не подумал =)
Мне правда для ноды надо, но  там ничего особенно не меняется:

     process[nameSpaceName][nameSpaceFuncName]();

то что пространство должно быть глобальным - это естественно, хотя если оно "публично" и не глобально большой проблемы изменить window(process) на parentObjectName не составит