# Как можно вызвать new c произвольной функцией?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть несколько функций:

```
a = function () {return 1}
b = function () {return 2}
c = function () {return 3}
```

И нужно создавать новые на основе одной из первоначальных функций через new, Причем имя исходной функции нужно передать как строку.

```
d = new "a" // было бы в идеале, но это не работает
```

Был похожий вопрос [Преобразование строки в переменную](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/64122/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E). Но он почему то не работает или я не неправильно понимаю как им пользоваться, window[nameSpaceName]nameSpaceFuncName

```
d = new window[a]() // ошибка
```

Подскажите как можно вызвать new с указанием имени функции, через строковую переменную. И если это возможно без ужасного eval().

Comment: Зачем это может быть нужно, кроме как для извращений?

Comment: Я пытаюсь сохранить массив с состоянием игры в JSON. И одно из значений в объекте это ссылка на функцию которая отображает спрайт, ссылка которая при конвертации конечно же не сохраняется. Так как я не могу сохранить ссылку, то придется создавать при загрузке новую функцию на основе предыдущей, через new. И что бы не делать большую конструкцию if else, для каждого вида спрайтов, очень пригодился бы автоматизированный способ создания новой функции через new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
a = function () {return 1}
d = new window['a']()
```

Comment: Спасибо,  все оказалось настолько просто.

Comment: @АлексейAl Я думаю вы бы могли и сами догадаться, если бы вникли в содержание вылетающей ошибки)